# How to recognize numbers according to this transition diagram?

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

Section 3.4.3 of the dragon book "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" (2nd Edition) describes the recognition process of numbers with optional `.` and `E` portions, according to the following transition diagram.

My problem is why are there no outgoing edges labeled "other" from states 14, 16, or 17? What if we encounter "other" symbols in these states? For example, how does it handle the input string `1.2345E+a`?

[image: number]

Answer (score 1):

The outgoing edges of a state in the automaton and their labels describe the valid input in this state. If any other symbol is encountered in the input string when automaton is in this state it will not accept string. If you consider the string in your example `1.2345E+a` the automaton will encounter `a` when it is in state 17 and since `a` is not a digit the automaton will reject the string as expected.

Comment: At the end of Section 3.4.4, it reads "We allow the transition diagram to read input until there is no possible next state, and **then take the longest lexeme that matched any pattern**". According to this strategy, shouldn't it return `1.2345`, `E`, `+`, and `a`?

Comment: I have tried it out in `flex`, it does return `1.2345`, `E`, `+`, and `a`.